# Mosquitto not printing messages on terminal

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am publishing messages from JavaScript code using Paho client. The messages are getting published as I can see them on subscriber side though I can't see any of them on terminal.

```
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("localhost", 9002, "myClient");
client.connect();
message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("hey");
message.destinationName = "/World";
client.send(message);
```

The command line using:

```
/usr/local/sbin/mosquitto -c /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

Comment: You can't see them where? You've shown the publishing code, but not explained how you are subscribing to them. Messages will not be printed in the mosquitto broker logs by default

Comment: Also topics really shouldn't start with a '/'

Comment: I am publishing them on mosquito broker but I can't see them on the mosquitto client.

Comment: Edit the question to include the command line you are using with the client

Comment: @hardillb : added

Comment: No, for the client not the broker

Comment: @hardillb: I am using above mentioned code only in my javascript and when I access using client.subscribe, I am able to get all the messages... however i can't see on the broker itself. The broker just displaying that client connected....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broker will not print messages to the console unless put in full verbose mode, this is not intended to be a way to view messages, but a debug tool to fix problems.

You can enable verbose mode by adding `-v` to the command line.

If you want to see all the messages following through the broker then using mosquitto_sub is a better option

```
mosquitto_sub -v -t '#'
```

Where # is the topic wildcard

Comment: hmm.. with your suggestion, i tried /usr/local/sbin/mosquitto -v -c /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf and somehow see more information on the console, but anyhow thanks for clearing this : The broker will not print messages to the console unless put in full verbose mode, this is not intended to be a way to view messages